# python sleep progress bar issue not working fine

Tags: python

I referred to one post of stackoverflow and created a progress bar for waiting but it does not work as expected. Can someone please help me out

```
def progress(count, total, suffix='waiting'):
    bar_len = 60

    filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

    percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
    bar = '=' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)

    sys.stdout.write('[%s] %s%s ...%s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', suffix))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def sleeper(seconds):
    for i in range(seconds):
        progress(i+1, seconds)
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1
```

When i call sleeper(10) after 5 seconds it messes up.

Comment: It's probably easier to use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) or [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html). What do you expect to happen? Or do you expect something that is not possible in existing libraries?

Comment: used tqdm and it works fine. thanks. post your comment as answer and will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to decrement `seconds` for each iteration, which decreases the `total` of the progress bar and skews the bar ratio:

Remove this line:

```
seconds -= 1
```